# Generalization of Wigner overlap formula

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, wigner-transform

I want to generalize the Wigner overlap formula,
$Tr( F G ) = 2 \pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dq W_F(q,p) W_G(q,p)$,
where $W_F(q,p)$ and $W_G(q,p)$ are the Wigner functions of the operators $F$ and $G$, respectively.

This formula is stated in literature for two operators $F,G$ (see e.g. *Measuring the quantum states of light* by Ulf Leonhardt) and some sources state that it is easy to generalize it to more than two operators.

My approach was to proof the statement for two operators and try to adapt the proof for three operators, hoping to find some pattern.

Thus, first my approach for two operators $F$ and $G$:
\begin{align}
Tr[FG] &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dq_1 \langle q_1 | F G |q_1 \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dq_1 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dq_2 \langle q_1 | F | q_2 \rangle \langle q_2 |G |q_1 \rangle \\ 
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_1 \langle q- \frac{x_1}{2} | F | q + \frac{x_1}{2} \rangle \langle q + \frac{x_1}{2} |G |q -\frac{x_1}{2} \rangle \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_1 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_2 \langle q- \frac{x_1}{2} | F | q + \frac{x_1}{2} \rangle \langle q - \frac{x_2}{2} |G |q +\frac{x_2}{2} \rangle \delta(x_1+x_2) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_1 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dp \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{ip(x_1+x_2)} \langle q- \frac{x_1}{2} | F | q + \frac{x_1}{2} \rangle \langle q - \frac{x_2}{2} |G |q +\frac{x_2}{2} \rangle \\
&=2 \pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dp \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_1 \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{ipx_1} \langle q- \frac{x_1}{2} | F | q +  \frac{x_1}{2} \rangle \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_2 e^{ip x_2}\langle q - \frac{x_2}{2} |G |q +\frac{x_2}{2} \rangle \\
&= 2 \pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} W_F(q,p) W_G(q,p)
\end{align}

Now I try to generalize this as similar as possible for three operators $F, G, H$:
\begin{align}
Tr[FGH] &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dq_1 \langle q_1|FGH |q_1\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dq_1 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dq_2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dq_3 \langle q_1|F|q_2 \rangle \langle q_2|G|q_3 \rangle \langle q_3| H |q_1\rangle\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_1 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_3 \langle q - \frac{x_1}{2}|F|q + \frac{x_1}{2} \rangle \langle q + \frac{x_1}{2} |G|q - \frac{x_3}{2} \rangle \langle q - \frac{x_3}{2} | H |q - \frac{x_1}{2}\rangle\\
&= ...
\end{align}

Well, one observes that the trick from the proof for two operators doesn't work here, because if I choose $x_2$ to be $-x_1$ for the middle part, we require $x_3 = - x_2$, hence $x_3 = x_1$. So, the last part would have the form $|q-\frac{x_1}{2} | H |q - \frac{x_1}{2}\rangle$ and not those we require to proceed.

Is there anything (stupid?) that I oversee?
Does anyone have an idea how one can prove the formula for three operators?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why would you think there is a similar formula for triples? Any reason at all?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I suspect he is misinformed about the properties of the star product inside phase-space integrals.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Sure you are not over-estimating this? It could just be a 'works for 1, works for 2 => must work always' induction.

Comment: @CosmasZachos That's why I asked the OP, rather than speculating.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I've read the statement for two operators, followed by the remark "This formula can easily be generalized."

This was, what made me thinking that there should be any kind of generalization and as I couldn't proof something similar for n operators, I tried it with 3. But probably I got the word "generalization" wrong?

So, is this remark simply wrong or is there any other "generalization" one can think of (beside the one Cosmas gave in his answer)? (e.g. with Wigner functions with two arguments, like the wigner function of two states after passing a beam splitter, ...)

Comment: Well, "generalization" is indeed not very precise. There are many aspects of this which could be generalized.  And "generalization" could mean various things (same simple form, or more involved form ... ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be profoundly misunderstanding the fundamental isomorphism of phase-space quantum mechanics. What you call "Wigner functions" are but Weyl symbols,
$$f(x,p) = \hbar\int\!\!dy ~ e^{-iyp}\langle x+\hbar y/2| F |  x-\hbar y/2 \rangle ,$$
c-number functions of phase space, so that
$$
h\operatorname{Tr} F = \int\!\! dx dp ~ f(x,p),\\
h\operatorname{Tr} (F G) = \int\!\! dx dp ~ f(x,p)\star g(x,p), \\
h\operatorname{Tr} (FGH) = \int\!\! dx dp ~ f(x,p)\star g(x,p)\star h(x,p),\\
h\operatorname{Tr} (FGHK) = \int\!\! dx dp ~ f(x,p)\star g(x,p)\star h(x,p)\star k(x,p), ...
$$
etc, utilizing the fundamental isomorphism of the Wigner map,
$$
FG\mapsto f\star g   =  f \, \exp{\left( \frac{i \hbar}{2} \left(\overleftarrow{\partial }_x \overrightarrow{\partial }_p -\overleftarrow{\partial}_p \overrightarrow{\partial}_x \right) \right)}  \, g  \\
= \hbar^2\int\!\! dy dy'~~e^{-ip(y+y')}
\langle x+\hbar(y+y')/2  |F|x-\hbar(y-y')/2  \rangle   \\  \times \langle x+\hbar(y'-y)/2  | G |x-\hbar (y+y')/2   \rangle .
$$

The [star product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyal_product) is associative, like the QM operators on the left, so no grouping parentheses are warranted.

*However*, you may convince yourself of a [***basic fact***](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf) of phase space QM, that *only one star  inside a phase space integral may be dismissed* (integrated out by parts), never more. Check this.

So you have, indeed,
$$
 \int\!\! dx dp ~ f(x,p)\star g(x,p) 
= \int\!\! dx dp ~ f(x,p) g(x,p), 
$$
but that's as far as the starless train goes. From this point on,
$$
h\operatorname{Tr} (FGH) = \bbox[yellow,5px]{ \int\!\! dx dp ~ f(x,p)\star g(x,p)\star h(x,p)  \\ =  \int\!\! dx dp ~ f(x,p)~~ \Big ( g(x,p)\star h(x,p)\Big  )\\ = \int\!\! dx dp ~ \Big ( f(x,p)\star g(x,p) \Big ) ~~ h(x,p)  },
$$
and so on. Your text should have taught you this.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, my text hasn't told me this. My text didn't even introduce the star product and I'm pretty sure that my text calls W a "Wigner function". It introduces the overlap formula as follows: "A remarkable property of the Wigner representation is the overlap formula for the Wigner functions $W_1$ and $W_2$ of two arbitrary operators $F_1$ and $F_2$.". Therefore, please excuse my nomenclature!

Comment: So, to come back to the subject of your ansewr;
As mentioned in the comment under my initial post, I tried to prove this generalization because I found a text, stating that this formula can easily be generalized. Your answer shows that the generalization to three or more operators doesn't work. Is the remark that the overlap formula can be easily generalized simply nonsense or can one imagine any other "generalization", e.g. to multimode states (and their wigner functions), like we know them from mixing two quantum states at a beam splitter? (So, I probably got "generalization" wrong.)

Comment: It is the simple overlap simplification which is (magnificently handy) nonsense: it does not even hold for other orderings, beyond Wigner-Weyl! The real generalization is for the chain of star  products, where only one star can be integrated out to a bland overlap. A Wigner function is the Wigner map of the density matrix, so the above also holds for Wigner functions. But there is nothing special about plain overlaps without stars, beyond (illusory) simplicity. Does this fully answer the question?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think the first part of my question - why my apporach does not work - is fully answered, because you showed that the generalisation to more states is nonsense. The second part - which generalization was meant - is not fully answered yet, but as there seems to be no obvious generalization, this question only can be answered finally by the author of the text. 
Therefore, I think we are as close as we can get to a full answer. I am going to mark your answer as the solution of this question.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks. I suspect "generalization" includes extension, that is, adoption of adaptations such as unclasped star products. If our booklet is too concise to your taste, you might try an extensive book by Wolfgang Schleich.